# What is system data and how to make it take less place?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

My mac has a problem that I have a system data that it seems every time I look at it, is a little bit bigger.

It now got to almost 60gb, half my hard disk.

Even with system scan tools, I can't seem to find what is that 60GB, and how to trim it.

So what is system data and how can I trim it? Most if not all answers I found on other sites was 'oh just grab this app (that you have to pay for) and it will help!'. I can't believe its the only option I would have.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend OmniDiskSweeper, which is free. Apple's categories are very broad and imprecise.